# Setup Jenkins in remote server and connect to local computer

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, ios-simulator

Currently, I am using Jenkins for my iOS continuous integration. I can run on localhost and everything is okay.

[image]

I set up like this in my localhost.

1) Can I deploy jenkins to remote server for my iOS projects? It is because most of the server are using window.

2) If I have to deploy to window server, how my iPhone simulator will run? Is it like I host to window server and connect to my mac computer? How shall I do? I just want my colleagues to change build setting remotely and build remotely.

Comment: There are iOS compile server hosting services online

Comment: I need to use Jenkins, fastlane together. Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood the question, but why not install Jenkins master on any computer you want and run the iOS jobs on a Mac slave? you can restrict a job to run on a specific slave and you can add nodes to Jenkins using ssh.

For example:

- Jenkins master - Remote windows machine
- Jenkins Slave - Mac machine connected to master using ssh

Configure in.Touch iOS job to run on the mac slave (configure -> Restrict where this project can be run)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have research sth like this. 
https://www.cloudbees.com/

I want to deploy my jenkins server to somewhere so that people can remotely access and modify configuration,etc. 

Problem of deploying to remote server is that
1) need mac server
2) I need some specific requirement like fastlane, ios simulator, xcode,etc

Is there any host that okay for my requirement? Or Is it possible to open access in my localhost? (people can remotely change configuration in my computer.not via teamviewer though)

Comment: Sorry for the late response - I was abroad :) 
If I understood correctly you have a Jenkins master that on it you are running your job. what I suggested is to have a remote machine with Jenkins master installed on it, connect your current machine as a slave to Jenkins by adding it as a new node, and then give access to people to the Jenkins master, keeping your slave as a black box to dev without access from outside. configure the job to run specifically on the machine you're running it now.

Adding new node - http://Jenkinsmaster:port/computer/ --> New Node